# Loading .xlsx file with multiple sheets to Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I am trying to load an excel file with multiple sheets in it. It is not a CSV file. So I am trying to use read_excel and then giving the reference to the file but still unable to load it.

How do I correct this code?

[Code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORDLS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Prefix your file name by `r` (raw strings) else `\Users` will be considered as an unicode sequence:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\...")
          # HERE --^
```

Comment: Thankyou kind sir. It worked. Appreciate it

Comment: @AttitudeBlack if this answers your question then please consider accepting it